# Redirecionamento com Ajax no ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou usando Ajax para salvar os dados do formulário.
O problema é que após salvar os dados não têm como
redirecionar para a "Action Index", onde é listado os clientes
cadastrados, pois a requisição foi feita em Ajax.
Pensei em criar uma PartialView para isso e renderizá-la com jQuery, porém ficaria redundante pois já existe uma View para isso,
que é a home do sistema, como havia dito.
Há alguma outra alternativa para isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz o redirect no sucesso do ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: minhaurl,
        data: $("#meuform").serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";

        }
    });
```

Com isso você garante que só manda caso receba um 200 do servidor.

Comment: Valeu Ricardo! Só mudei para window.location.href = "./Home/Index", pois dessa forma que você colocou o JavaScript não reconheceu que era C#.